# Adding a button to the default incoming call screen in Android

Tags: android

I'm in the process of developing an Android app for which I need to add a button on the incoming call screen. Is it possible to add a new button to the existing incoming call screen or should I create a custom screen specific to my app?

Edit:
I want to add a button in addition to the Answer and Decline buttons in the screen that appears when there is an incoming call.

Comment: What do you mean by 'incoming call screen'. Are you working in Eclipse?

Comment: The screen that appears with the Answer and Decline button.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Sorry, I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same funcionality and found this open source project, http://code.google.com/p/incomingcallplus/

Haven't played with it yet, but seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: @guigouz Can you please, provide a source code for incomingcallplus? It isn't available on link in your answer. I really need it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes and No.

No, you can't add a new button to an existing app. But Yes, you can *replace* that app (in this case, the dialer) with one that has the button you want. When users install your app, they'll pick whether they want to use *your* app or the built-in dialer app to make and receive calls.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add something like the following to your main.xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/helloButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" text="Hello Button" />
```

Then in your 'Launcher' activity, you'll need to assign a handler to handle clicks, etc.

Comment: I'm new to android app development, so please excuse if I'm not using the correct terminologies. If I add the above button code to main.xml, the button appears only when my app is launched. However, I want to add a button to an existing Activity, i.e. the native incoming call screen. Can you please help as to how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on the default dialer screen then I don't think that's possible without disabling controls of the dialer and having your transparent activity over the dialer; user will be able to interact with your activity and can only use the dialer on clicking the back button.

You might want to go with the custom design.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ujwal. I want to do it on the default screen that appears when there is an incoming call, and not the default dialer screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addInvitePopup(final String number,Context c){
    //check if pref is ok with invite in call
   // if(!Preferences.getInstance(c.getInviteInCall())){return ; }
    // sets the WindowManager
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.x = 250;
    params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
     final Context ct =c;

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Testing");

    LinearLayout ly = new LinearLayout(c);
    ly.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button inviteButton = new Button(c);
    inviteButton.setClickable(true);
    inviteButton.setBackgroundDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
    inviteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "adding to blacklist..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(ct.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images));
            v.setClickable(false);
           // sendMessage(v, number);

            //Track this event:
            //MixPanelTracking.setPropKeyValue(getApplicationContext(), null, null, "Add friend - During Call");
        }
    });
```

also dont forget to add permission : android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in your manifest file